# How to persist data or state across child components in react.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, state, reactjs-flux

Okay, I am seeking out the best way to persist data across child components. As per my knowledge, to communicate between a parent and a child, I should pass a callback to the child component as props. Now, if I need to change the state of the parent, I just call the callback and it sets the state of the parent. Correct?

But that is not my requirement. Let's consider a scenario where I have multiple children and all of them share the same data. What I need is, if I change the state/date in any of the children, then the data change should reflect in other child components as well. Invoking the callback will only change the state of the parent, how can I update the passed props in other children along with it?

I hope that was not confusing. I am using Flux architecture in my application. I do have an alternative solution for my problem using actions and dispatcher. However, I want to know whether there is a smarter and standard way of doing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just change the state of the parent, that will trigger a re-render of the parent, pass whatever props (even if they are the same) to children and they will re-render with your new state.

Whether you pass a function from parent to children, or have children emit an action via a dispatcher (which would probably be the preferred method if you’re using flux anyway), the theory is the same, parent state change and pass props to children.

Comment: If you use flux, then the action/ dispatcher route is better than the callback to the parent: using callbacks to allow child to alter parent state, is an antipattern. Best avoided, for it makes code harder to maintain/ debug.

Comment: I agree in general, but it goes hand-in-hand with using component state, if you're going to hide state within components then manipulation via callbacks is tolerable, no different from passing those callbacks to a store for example. I'm not a fan of component state either, but that is the pattern the poster is using already.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I am not against state per se, and I understand that in this case it is part of the setup. But state should deliberately be hidden from the outside world as much as possible. This is by design. So any access to it also best avoided, or at least a path to be tread with care. To keep app manageable, probably best to pass callbacks to either stores or children, but preferably not both.

Comment: Yeah, I think we're on the same page, I've added a small corollary to my answer, ultimately its up to the use-case. Personally, I prefer eliminating all state from components but people have different preferred patterns.

Comment: Great explanations guys. I am going with the option flux. I think using child Component to emit actions will be a better way to update states across all other child Components. Thank you for your answers.